# Sliding a point on a curve

Tags: matlab

I have tried the following code in Matlab 2017b:

```
function demo()

clc,close all

fig=figure();

ax=axes(fig,...
    'Units','Normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6],...
    'XGrid','on',...
    'YGrid','on')

slider=uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.9,0.6,0.05],...
    'Tag','slider1',...
    'Min',0,...
    'Max',10,...
    'Value',1,...
    'Callback',@slider_callback);

x=linspace(0,10);
y=1/3*x.^2;
plot(x,y,'b-')
grid on
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
hold on
p=plot(1,1/3,'ro')
hold off

    function slider_callback(hObject,eventdata)
        x=hObject.Value;
        p.XData=x;
        p.YData=1/3*x.^2;
        drawnow
    end

end
```

Currently, I move the slider and it is only when I release the mouse button that the point is updated. What changes can I make so that I see the point move as I drag the slider?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to VIG's comment, I was able to do this:

```
function demo()

clc,close all

fig=figure();

% initialize some parameters
xstart=4;
ystart=1/3*4^2;

ax=axes(fig,...
    'Units','Normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6],...
    'XGrid','on',...
    'YGrid','on');

slider=uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.9,0.6,0.05],...
    'Tag','slider1',...
    'Min',0,...
    'Max',10,...
    'Value',xstart);

addlistener(slider,'Value',...
    'PostSet',@(hObject, event) slider_callback(slider, event));

x=linspace(0,10);
y=1/3*x.^2;
plot(x,y,'b-')
grid on
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
hold on
plot([-5,10],[0,0],'k-');
plot([0,0],[-5,35],'k-');
p=plot(xstart,ystart,'ro');
a1=quiver(0,0,xstart,ystart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a2=quiver(0,0,0,xstart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a3=quiver(0,0,xstart,0,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
d=plot([0,xstart,xstart],[ystart,ystart,0],'k--');
hold off

    function slider_callback(hObject,eventdata)
        x=hObject.Value;
        p.XData=x;
        p.YData=1/3*x.^2;
        a1.UData=x;
        a1.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a2.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a3.UData=x;
        d.XData=[0,x,x];
        d.YData=[1/3*x.^2,1/3*x.^2,0];
        drawnow
    end

end
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

I'd love to hear any further suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a listener, and then you might omit the callback when creating the slider:

```
slider=uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.9,0.6,0.05],...
    'Tag','slider1',...
    'Min',0,...
    'Max',10,...
    'Value',1);

addlistener(slider,'Value','PostSet',@(hObject, event) slider_callback(slider, event));
```

---

EDIT:

You can use [`impoint`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoint.html?requestedDomain=true). Then add:

```
....
addlistener(slider,'Value',...
    'PostSet',@(hObject, event) slider_callback(slider, event));

h = impoint(gca,xstart,ystart);
setColor(h,'r')
point = h;
addNewPositionCallback(h,@(h) make_constraint(h));

x=linspace(0,10);
...
```

and delete the plot `p=plot(xstart,ystart,'ro');`.

In `slider_callback` replace

```
p.XData=x;
p.YData=1/3*x.^2;
```

with

```
setPosition(point, [x 1/3*x^2])
```

and add

```
function make_constraint(h)
        fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('impoint',[0 10],[1/3*h(1).^2 1/3*h(1).^2]);
        % Enforce boundary constraint function using setPositionConstraintFcn
        setPositionConstraintFcn(point,fcn);
        a1.UData=h(1);
        a1.VData=1/3*h(1).^2;
        a2.VData=1/3*h(1).^2;
        a3.UData=h(1);
        d.XData=[0,h(1),h(1)];
        d.YData=[1/3*h(1).^2,1/3*h(1).^2,0];
        set(slider, 'Value', h(1))
        drawnow
    end
```

So total code:

```
function stackover()

clc,close all

fig=figure();

% initialize some parameters
xstart=4;
ystart=1/3*4^2;

ax=axes(fig,...
    'Units','Normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6],...
    'XGrid','on',...
    'YGrid','on');


slider=uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.9,0.6,0.05],...
    'Tag','slider1',...
    'Min',0,...
    'Max',10,...
    'Value',xstart);

addlistener(slider,'Value',...
    'PostSet',@(hObject, event) slider_callback(slider, event));

h = impoint(gca,xstart,ystart);
setColor(h,'r')
point = h;
addNewPositionCallback(h,@(h) make_constraint(h));

x=linspace(0,10);
y=1/3*x.^2;
plot(x,y,'b-')
grid on
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
hold on
plot([-5,10],[0,0],'k-');
plot([0,0],[-5,35],'k-');

a1=quiver(0,0,xstart,ystart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a2=quiver(0,0,0,xstart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a3=quiver(0,0,xstart,0,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
d=plot([0,xstart,xstart],[ystart,ystart,0],'k--');
hold off

    function slider_callback(hObject,eventdata)
        x=hObject.Value;
        setPosition(point, [x 1/3*x^2])
        a1.UData=x;
        a1.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a2.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a3.UData=x;
        d.XData=[0,x,x];
        d.YData=[1/3*x.^2,1/3*x.^2,0];
        drawnow
    end

    function make_constraint(h)
        fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('impoint',[0 10],[1/3*h(1).^2 1/3*h(1).^2]);
        % Enforce boundary constraint function using setPositionConstraintFcn
        setPositionConstraintFcn(point,fcn);
        a1.UData=h(1);
        a1.VData=1/3*h(1).^2;
        a2.VData=1/3*h(1).^2;
        a3.UData=h(1);
        d.XData=[0,h(1),h(1)];
        d.YData=[1/3*h(1).^2,1/3*h(1).^2,0];
        set(slider, 'Value', h(1))
        drawnow
    end

end
```

ps `demo()` is an existing MATLAB function, so it's best that you choose another name.

---

EDIT 2:

In the case that you can't use `impoint`, you have to add 3 listeners:

- `WindowButtonUpFcn`: detects when mouse is released.
- `WindowButtonMotionFcn`: detects when mouse is moved.
- `ButtonDownFcn`: detects when mouse is clicked.

The first 2 need to be attached to the figure:

```
fig=figure('WindowButtonUpFcn',@drop,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@move);
```

The last one can be attached to the plot only:

```
p=plot(xstart,ystart,'ro','ButtonDownFcn',@click);
```

Since `WindowButtonUpFcn` and `WindowButtonMotionFcn` are for the whole figure, these will always be called on motion or release of the mouse. But we only want the functions to be executed when dragging the point. To do this a variable (`dragging`) is introduced. In the `click` function this variable is set to `1`, to indicate that we're dragging.

Then while moving the mouse, the point, quivers and slider are updated in `move`. Here a control unit is added to make sure you don't drag the point out of the boundaries of the slider.

When the mouse is released, `dragging` is set to `0` again.

Of course it would be nice to know when you are hovering above the point, so that you know that if you click now, you can drag the point. To do this we can set the pointerbehaviour with

```
iptSetPointerBehavior(p, pointerBehavior);
```

Here `pointerBehavior` is a struct containing 3 functions:

- `enterFcn`: executed when mouse enters object.
- `exitFcn`: executed when mouse exits object.
- `traverseFcn`: executed when mouse enters object and when it moves in object.

We don't need the last one. When entering the mousepointer is set to be a cross with arrows on the edges, when leaving the point is transformed to the (regular) arrow. (for more info see [iptSetPointerBehavior](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/iptsetpointerbehavior.html) and [hggroup](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hggroup.html))

The total code is then:

```
function stackover()

clc,close all

fig=figure('WindowButtonUpFcn',@drop,'WindowButtonMotionFcn',@move);

% initialize some parameters
xstart=4;
ystart=1/3*4^2;

dragging = 0;

ax=axes('Units','Normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.2,0.6,0.6],...
    'XGrid','on',...
    'YGrid','on');

slider=uicontrol(...
    'Parent',fig,...
    'Style','slider',...
    'Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.2,0.9,0.6,0.05],...
    'Tag','slider1',...
    'Min',0,...
    'Max',10,...
    'Value',xstart);

addlistener(slider,'Value',...
    'PostSet',@(hObject, event) slider_callback(slider, event));


pointerBehavior.enterFcn = @(figHandle, currentPoint) set(figHandle, 'Pointer', 'fleur');
pointerBehavior.exitFcn  = @(figHandle, currentPoint) set(figHandle, 'Pointer', 'arrow');
pointerBehavior.traverseFcn = [];



x=linspace(0,10);
y=1/3*x.^2;
plot(x,y,'b-')
grid on
xlabel('x-axis')
ylabel('y-axis')
hold on
plot([-5,10],[0,0],'k-');
plot([0,0],[-5,35],'k-');
p=plot(xstart,ystart,'ro','ButtonDownFcn',@click);

iptSetPointerBehavior(p, pointerBehavior);     % set behaviour of pointer when over p
iptPointerManager(gcf);                        % let figure know what you're doing

a1=quiver(0,0,xstart,ystart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a2=quiver(0,0,0,xstart,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
a3=quiver(0,0,xstart,0,0,...
    'LineWidth',1,...
    'Color','red');
d=plot([0,xstart,xstart],[ystart,ystart,0],'k--');
hold off

    function slider_callback(hObject,eventdata)
        x=hObject.Value;
        p.XData=x;
        p.YData=1/3*x.^2;
        a1.UData=x;
        a1.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a2.VData=1/3*x.^2;
        a3.UData=x;
        d.XData=[0,x,x];
        d.YData=[1/3*x.^2,1/3*x.^2,0];
        drawnow
    end


    function click(hObject,eventdata)
        dragging = 1;
    end
    function drop(hObject,eventdata)
        dragging = 0;
    end
    function move(hObject,eventdata)
        if dragging
            mouse = ax.CurrentPoint;
            x = mouse(1,1);

            if x >= slider.Max
                x = slider.Max;
            elseif x <= slider.Min
                x = slider.Min;
            end

            p.XData=x;
            p.YData=1/3*x.^2;
            a1.UData=x;
            a1.VData=1/3*x.^2;
            a2.VData=1/3*x.^2;
            a3.UData=x;
            d.XData=[0,x,x];
            d.YData=[1/3*x.^2,1/3*x.^2,0];
            slider.Value = x;
            drawnow
        end
    end


end
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I've posted an update above. I'd love to see if it is possible to drag the point with a mouse as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've got to spend some time with your suggestions. Excellent.

Comment: Oops. I don't have the image processing toolbox. Any other way? And I want to thank you for your help. :-)

Comment: @David There sure is another way, please see `EDIT 2`.

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying Edit 2 again, but I get an error message regarding iptSetPointerBehavior and iptPointerManager. The error says I have to have the Image Processing Toolbox. I commented both of these lines out and then it worked. Is this OK? I'm going to take some time tomorrow carefully reading every sentence of your beautiful explanation and then typing in the code a line at a time. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @David you're right, my apologies. I thought I checked for the dependence of the tool boxes. This only affects the pointer behaviour, I'll see if I can find a more manual solution.